# Table to fill remaining space inside another cell (IE8)

Tags: html, css, html-table, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to get the table "innerTable" to fill all remaining space inside another table. The browser in question is IE8 (no compatibility mode, IE8 browser mode, Doc mode IE8 Standards). The table won't scale to the containing TD. I tried to enclose the table in DIV on various depths (TD, TR, ..), but it did not help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
html, body, #full {
    height: 100%;
}
.myTable {
    height: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 300px;
}
.fit {
    height: 1px;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<table class="myTable">
<tr class="fit"><td><h1> hello </h1></td></tr>

<tr style="height: 100%;">
    <td id="problem">
        <table id="innerTable" style="height: 100%; white-space: nowrap;">
        <tr style="height: 100%;">
            <td style="height: 100%;">
                Hello World!!!
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="fit"><td><h2> world </h2></td></tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

If I style the td#problem to `height: 100%`, innerTable fits the remaining space, but the td#problem scales to something 'big', something larger then html block. I thought that 100% for TD's height should refer to containing block (TR in this case, which I tried with-and-without height:100%), but it does not seem so.

BTW. design works in other browsers, it is probably just IE8 that causes a problem

---

Just tested, the site works on ALL other document and browser modes in IE8, except the one I ought to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this link. i guess this is will help you.
>   Do these two things to fill the spaces.

```
table tr td{padding:0;}

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
```

> or you an do this

```
table tr td{position:relative;}

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%"></table>
```

[HERE THE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/B25d7/)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I was maybe not specific enough, it is only height that is of importance. All the elements except the TD#problem are already styled with height: 100%.

Comment: can you put your code in jsfiddle? then it will be more clear

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jdjpL/ Works in Firefox (as it should), IE8 just jokes on the whole jsfiddle.

Comment: Still no luck. All those changes only took away spacing and padding within cells, but the result is still the same (but at least now I can see that the TD#problem with height: 100% scales to either body or html elements). As I mentioned, this is a IE8 specific problem, other browsers do render the page correctly.

Comment: Position worked in this simple scenario, though not in the complex final solution. I ended up with lots of other positioning, transparency and layer issues. But yes, in my testcase above, a combination of position relative/absolute does the trick.

Comment: I accept the proposed solution as a valid answer, as it does solve the supplied testcase.